# getElementById not working in class method

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```html
<div id='verse'>
    <p id='text'>
        <span id = 'reference'>random stuff here</span> 
     random stuff here
     </p>
  </div>
```

JS:

```js
class Verse {
  ...
  update() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'text';
    document.getElementById('reference').innerHTML = 'reference';
  }
  ...
}
```

Whenever I call `.update` in an instance of `Verse`, the paragraph element's text changes without a problem but trying to change the span's text gives me an error: `TypeError: Cannot set properties of null`. Does not work with innerText either. It works fine if I change it outside of the class. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `innerHTML` on `#text` replaces the contents of the `<p>` entirely, so when you subsequently try to access `#reference` it no longer exists.

The simplest way to avoid this would be to add another span and replace its text instead of the entire `<p>`.

```html
<div id='verse'>
  <p>
    <span id='reference'>random stuff here</span> 
    <span id='text'>random stuff here</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there some way I could get around this?